# Select a dropdown value based on first 2 digits of 11 digits number of a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field that accepts 11 digits VAT number, where first two digits represent states, followed by any 9 digits (eg: 09123456789, where 09 represents Uttar pradesh as a state in India, and like wise).

```
                  <label class="flabel">VAT Registration Number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-element" name="vat" id="vat1" placeholder="Please Enter 11 Digits VAT registration number" required data-bv-notempty-message="This is required" pattern="^(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-5])[0-9]{9}$" data-bv-regexp-message="Please enter a valid VAT number" >
```

There is a STATE dropdown with names of states and option values as given below:

```
                        <select class="form-element" name="address" id="state" required data-bv-notempty-message="This is required">
                        <option value="">Please select</option>
                            <option value="35">Andaman and Nicobar Islands</option>
                            <option value="28">Andhra Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="04">Chandigarh</option>
                            <option value="22">Chhattisgarh</option>
                            <option value="26">Dadra and Nagar Haveli</option>
                            <option value="25">Daman and Diu</option>
                            <option value="07">Delhi (NCT)</option>
                            <option value="30">Goa</option>
                            <option value="24">Gujarat</option>
                            <option value="06">Haryana</option>
                            <option value="02">Himachal Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="01">Jammu and Kashmir</option>
                            <option value="29">Karnataka</option>
                            <option value="31">Lakshadweep</option>
                            <option value="23">Madhya Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="27">Maharashtra</option>
                            <option value="21">Orissa</option>
                            <option value="34">Puducherry</option>
                            <option value="03">Punjab</option>
                            <option value="08">Rajasthan</option>
                            <option value="11">Sikkim</option>
                            <option value="33">Tamil Nadu</option>
                            <option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
                            <option value="05">Uttarakhand</option>
                            <option value="09">Uttar Pradesh</option>
                            <option value="19">West Bengal</option>
                  </select>
```

What's needed, that if somebody enters the 11 digits in the VAT Registration Number text-box, the corresponding state should get selected in the STATE dropdown, based on the FIRST TWO digits of the VAT Number.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function (){
        $('#vat1').change(function(){
             $('#state').val($(this).val());
        });

    });
</script>
```

As I enter the first two digits and press a TAB, the state gets selected, but when I enter the 11 digits, the state value goes off.

Comment: Adding to this, now i also have a list of cities for each state. So, as the STATE is automatically selected on the basis of first 2 digits of VAT entered, the list of CITIES should come for that particular state in another dropdown. That means, on entering the VAT number, based on the first 2 digits, the state gets automatically selected and the corresponding city list gets populated in another dropdown, that the user now can select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the first two digits should be taken from the input. Also it possible to show selected state immediately after the first two digits are entered while user is still typing using `.on('input, function(){})` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#vat1').on('input', function() {
        var v = $(this).val().substr(0,2);
        $('#state').val(v);
    });
});
```

---

It is possible to check that the select option for input number exits. If there is no such option it possible to do some error handling, for example here the class `error` is set on the input control to highlight it with red border (that is configured by CSS):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#vat1').on('input', function () {
        // clear error state
        $('#vat1').removeClass('error');
        // clear selected value
        $('#state').val("");

        // check that input length is at least 2 symbols
        if ($(this).val().length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        // select first two symbols from input
        var v = $(this).val().substr(0, 2);

        // check that option with given code exists
        var opt = $("#state option[value =" + v + "]");
        if (opt.length == 0) {
            // there is no option for given input
            // do whatever is needed here
            // for example show red border
            $('#vat1').addClass('error');
            // or alert message
            alert("We dont serve this State as of now");
            // or anything other...
        }
        else {
            // select State by input
            $('#state').val(v);
        }
    });
});
```

CSS to show red border on error:

```
.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
.error:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

It is also possible to do any other actions on error.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kx55oojx/3/

Comment: I used this solution.

Comment: Another Problem: Since we dont serve all STATES, the dropdown dosent have all 35 STATES. (eg, option value 10, 12, 13, 14, 18 etc are not there). So, if a user enters 10 (as first 2 digits), no value should be selected in the list (this currently works), but should show an alert to the user "We dont serve this State as of now"

Comment: Adding to this, now i also have a list of cities for each state. So, as the STATE is automatically selected on the basis of first 2 digits of VAT entered, the list of CITIES should come for that particular state in another dropdown. That means, on entering the VAT number, based on the first 2 digits, the state gets automatically selected and the corresponding city list gets populated in another dropdown, that the user now can select.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function (){
            $('#vat1').change(function(){

                 var stateId = $(this).val().substr(0,2);

                 if($('#state').find('option[value="'+ stateId +'"]').length > 0){ 
                   $('#state').val(stateId);
                 }else{
                   alert('We do not provide service in selected state');
                 }

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Another Problem: Since we dont serve all STATES, the dropdown dosent have all 35 STATES. (eg, option value 10, 12, 13, 14, 18 etc are not there). So, if a user enters 10 (as first 2 digits), no value should be selected in the list (this currently works), but should show an alert to the user "We dont serve this State as of now".

Comment: Adding to this, now i also have a list of cities for each state. So, as the STATE is automatically selected on the basis of first 2 digits of VAT entered, the list of CITIES should come for that particular state in another dropdown. That means, on entering the VAT number, based on the first 2 digits, the state gets automatically selected and the corresponding city list gets populated in another dropdown, that the user now can select.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#vat1").change(function(){
      vat_id = $("#vat1").val().substr(0,2);
        if(vat_id){
        state_id = $("#state option[value =" + vat_id + "]").val();
        $("#state").val(state_id);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Another Problem: Since we dont serve all STATES, the dropdown dosent have all 35 STATES. (eg, option value 10, 12, 13, 14, 18 etc are not there). So, if a user enters 10 (as first 2 digits), no value should be selected in the list (this currently works), but should show an alert to the user "We dont serve this State as of now".

Comment: @MohammadAdnanKhan - If you don't have a corresponding state for 10, then state_id will remain empty. You can have a if..else condition there to popup an alert.

Comment: Adding to this, now i also have a list of cities for each state. So, as the STATE is automatically selected on the basis of first 2 digits of VAT entered, the list of CITIES should come for that particular state in another dropdown. That means, on entering the VAT number, based on the first 2 digits, the state gets automatically selected and the corresponding city list gets populated in another dropdown, that the user now can select.